# formatting array output for ajax

Tags: jquery

I created an array that contains the text values of a bunch of 'textarea' elements on my page like this:

```
    var textArray = [];
    $('[name=txtObjective]').each(function (i) {
        textArray.push($(this).val());
    });
```

However in order to pass to this ajax, I need the 'data' to look like this:

```
var data = {
    textarea1 : { id:'1343342', text:'a lot of text'},
    textarea2 : { id:'6774353', text:'some more text'}
}
```

Is there a way to do this with my current code?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the value for `id:` come from?

Comment: that will be the id of the textarea element, sorry I forgot to include that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = {};
$('textarea[name=txtObjective]').each(function(i) {
    data['textarea' + ++i] = { id: this.id, text: this.value };
});
```

Comment: @999cm999 Yes, it does, but you don't need the `textareaN` parameters, you can create an object with `id`s as parameters and `text`s as their values.